# How to process array element into MySQL with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get elements of an array, and put it to MySQL query using PHP like this:

```
$ArrayOne = {3, 5, 8, 2};
$sql = SELECT * from myTable WHERE id1='3' and id2='5' and id3='8' and id4='2';
```

I do it like this, but it's failed:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($ArrayOne); $i++) {
  $element.$i = $ArrayOne[$i];
}
  $sql = ("SELECT * from myTable WHERE id1=". $element.$i ." and id2=". $element.$i ." and id3=". $element.$i ." and id4=". $element.$i .");
```

I think the `$element.$i` has the same value, but I don't know how to get the different value of Array element.
And if I do like this, it's also wrong.

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($ArrayOne); $i++) {
  $element.$i = $ArrayOne[$i];    
  $sql = ("SELECT * from myTable WHERE id1=". $element.$i ." and id2=". $element.$i ." and id3=". $element.$i ." and id4=". $element.$i .");
}
```

Can any body give the solution?

Comment: May I encourage you to instead visit php.net and read up on the PDO library.  If you are going to start learning how to make php db queries it would be better to learn how to do it securely and efficiently as we'll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several mistake in your code

The first is:

```
$ArrayOne = {3, 5, 8, 2};
```

Should be:

```
$ArrayOne = array(3, 5, 8, 2);
```

2nd mistake, your `$sql` variable doesnt has enclosed between quotes  should be `$sql="your query";`

if your array has a fix length you dont have need to use a loop:

```
$ArrayOne = array(3, 5, 8, 2);

 $sql =  "SELECT     * 
     from       myTable 
     WHERE      id1='$ArrayOne[0]'
     and        id2='$ArrayOne[1]'
     and        id3='$ArrayOne[2]'
     and        id4='$ArrayOne[3]'";
```

For an array of variable length you can use the @Nightmare's answer

As side note:

Read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

You should learn PDO, if you are starting to learn php, do it the right way

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$count = count($ArrayOne);
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
    $where_arr[$i] = 'id'.$i.'='.$ArrayOne[$i];
}

$sql = "select * from myTable where ".implode(" and ",$where_arr);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nightmare. Yes, i think this can be the solution.