# Get array element and use it in mysql query with php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I want to make Mysql query like this :

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id='11' AND number='23' AND value='45' AND result='101' ");
```

I want to change the WHERE variable of mysql_query using '$myArray' array element.

```
$myArray[0] = array(11, 23, 45, 101);  => this is the current query
$myArray[1] = array(21, 31, 70, 58);
$myArray[2] = array(8, 77, 68, 94);
```

I tried to get result like this :

```
foreach($myArray[] as $singleRow) {
  foreach($singleRow as $myElement) { 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id='". $myElement ."' AND number='". $myElement ."' AND value='". $myElement . "' AND result='". $myElement ."' ");
  }
}
```

Or like this :

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($myArray); $i++) {
  foreach($myArray[$i] as $myElement) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id='". $myElement ."' AND number='". $myElement ."' AND value='". $myElement . "' AND result='". $myElement ."' ");
  }
}
```

Both are wrong ...  How to do the right one ?

Thanks

Comment: Use PDO or ADOdb since mysql_query is deprecated. With those you can execute a query by passing an array as parameter. Look into it :)

Also, your $myElement at the end has an extra " that would cause it to fail

Comment: You are right, it was a typo. I have removed the extra " . thanks

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as your question from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690267/how-to-process-array-element-into-mysql-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are trying to do this, especially considering mysql_* functions are being deprecated, but for the sake of learning, in this instance you *could* do something like this:

```
foreach($myArray as $row) { 
   $sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id='". $row[0] ."' AND number='". $row[1] ."' AND value='". $row[2] . "' AND result='". $row[3] ."' ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer cillosis. Actually what i want to do is this :
*) i have a table with more 100.000 rows. It has "id" column (auto_increment) and "value" column (int 0 or 1).
*) i want to looking for how many presence that match the binary pattern 2^10 (2 power of 10) that are "0000000000", "0000000001", "0000000010", "0000000011", ...... "1111111111".
*) This pattern can be searched using (for 3 digit pattern) `select count(*) match_count
from TheTable t1
join TheTable t2 on t1.id+1 = t2.id
join TheTable t3 on t1.id+2 = t3.id
where t1.value = 1 and t2.value = 0 and t3.value = 1`

Comment: Sorry, i have not got 15 reputation yet ... :(

Answer (score 0):

You're adding in too many loops, and not referencing the right variables at the right time:

```
foreach($myArray as $singleRow) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id='". $singleRow[0] ."' AND number='". $singleRow[1] ."' AND value='". $singleRow[2] . "' AND result='". $singleRow[3] ."' ");
}
```

I'd really recommend switching over to PDO or mysqli. Not only are mysql_* functions deprecated and very prone to sql injection, both PDO and mysqli allow you to send an array as the parameters and will take care of the quote-encapsulation for you.